# Output file location of BufferedWriter() in java project with 2 modules

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, module

I have a JavaFX project with 2 modules..

[Project structure][1]

public class SkiResortModel {

```
    private static final String FILE_NAME_RESORTS = "/SKI_RESORTS.csv";
```

//Code for reading file is:

```
private BufferedReader getReader() {
    InputStream inputStreamResorts = getClass().getResourceAsStream(SkiResortModel.FILE_NAME_RESORTS);
    assert inputStreamResorts != null;
    InputStreamReader readerResorts = new InputStreamReader(inputStreamResorts, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    return new BufferedReader(readerResorts);
}

private List<SkiResortModel> readFromFile() {
    try (BufferedReader reader = getReader()) {
        return reader.lines()
            .skip(1)
            .map(line -> new SkiResortModel(line.split(DELIMITER, 0)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("failed");
    }
}
```

//Code for writing file is:

```
private BufferedWriter getWriter(String filename) {
    try {
        String file = Objects.requireNonNull(getClass().getResource(filename)).getFile();
        return new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("wrong file " + filename);
    }
}

public void save() {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = getWriter(FILE_NAME_RESORTS)) {
        writer.write(
            "ENTITY_ID;NAME;REGION;COMMUNES_IN_RESORT;MASL_MIN;MASL_MAX;SKI_RUNS_KM;DRAG_LIFTS;CHAIR_LIFTS;CABLE_CARS;OPEN_LIFTS;SNOW_DEPTH_CM;VISITORS_TODAY;CAR_FREE;FUNPARK_AVAILABLE;IMAGE_URL");
        writer.newLine();
        int id = 100;
        for (SkiResortModel s : allSkiResorts) {
            writer.write(s.infoAsLine(";", id));
            writer.newLine();
            id++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

We have created a small application which displays the data in a table and allows for some modification. The data should then be written back into the original csv file.

The data is stored in the resources folder (screenshot). When the save function is called the data should then be written back into the original csv-file. However Intellij creates a new csv file under skiresorts-model/target.
I tried to indicate the path by copying the path from the context menue (Right click on file => Copy path / reference. I tried all the options to copy the path but then the program is unable to find the file. Strange is also that after I used copy path/reference
the program is unable to run even with the original path. The only thing that helps then is to check out another branch and return to the branch. Is this a bug in Intellij?

The save function is called from another class after the modifications have been done.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwtB2.png

Comment: What is returned by `getClass().getResource(filename)`? Try `getClassLoader().getResource()`. See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/resource-files.html

Comment: getClass().getResource(filename) => Gives targetfolder...How can I specify resource folder? getClassLoader().getResource() gives error